# Live search - Type as you go in Form - not working

Tags: livesearch

Just like PythonF in 2019, I am currently working on a database with MS Access 365. I am using the filtering of access to create a live-search in my form. Seems to work fine until I type something in that is not contained in the database. Getting runtime error 2185 instead of just giving an empty result. 'You can't reference a property or method for a control unless the control has the focus'. My code:

```
Option Compare Database
Private blnSpace As Boolean

Private Sub Form_Load()
Me.SearchText.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub Refresh_Click()
 With Me
 SearchText = ""
End With
Me.SearchText.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub SearchText_Change()
If blnSpace = False Then
Me.Requery
Refresh
SearchText.SetFocus
SearchText.SelStart = Len(Me.SearchText.Text)
End If
End Sub

Private Sub SearchText_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
If KeyAscii = 32 Then
blnSpace = True
Else
blnSpace = False
End If
End Sub
```

Added PythonF's code:

```
If Not (Me.Recordset.RecordCount = 0) Then
Me.SearchBox.SelStart = SearchLen
End If
```

Added Dim SearchLen
when it did not recognize the variable SearchLen

Would like to see PythonF's solution - he only said he fixed it but did not share the code that finally worked.

Comment: I resolved this issue by removing a 2nd table from the query.  My Contacts table had all the fields needed to run the query.  My 2nd table "Company" was in a 1:M Relationship with Contacts (I was hoping to use later as a lookup to the contacts).  My guess is that when a character string in the search field was not recognized, it did not know what to do, perhaps because there were two tables to look in, and could not reconcile which of the two tables to present the empty result, so it threw the unrelated error 'can't reference property or method for a control unless the control has the focus'.